# Core data does not load data in IOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6, simulator

I have developed an app which works well on iOS 5.1 but
after upgrading my IDE to X-CODE 4.5 and simulating my app on iOS 6, CoreData doesn't fetchData from myDataBase.SQLITE
and the returned NSInteger from

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

is always 0.
X-CODE 4.5 doesn't show any error! and the App doesn't crash, only shows an empty tableview! 
why this happens? 
should I change something in my app?

Comment: What makes you think you should have data on the database? Do you have a script that creates data when launching for the first time? Do you import it from somewhere? Do you import a sample database? Or were you expecting to see the same data you entered when testing iOS 5.1 version?

Comment: I have prepopulated my database with texts and I want to see them in a TableView. when I test my app in my iPhone (iOS 5.01) app works well and show data, but on the simulator(iOS 6) shows nothing.

Comment: You have prepopulated the database how? What I'm considering is that the simulator doesn't share the database when running on iOS6 and iOS5.1.

Comment: I have several copies of my app. none of them are showing data on the simulator. what do you suggest more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data between iOS 5 and iOS 6 simulator is not shared. The two simulators are completely independent. Since you're using sqlite as your core data persistent store, check the .sqlite file in the simulator platform folder that it actually has records.

As an aside, Core Data is NOT a database. It's a common misunderstanding that can lead to all sorts of conceptual issue later on. It can use sqlite as a persistent store, but the model is not a database.

Comment: wow thats great. as I had developed the app 10 month ago, I had forgotten to copy my prepopulated database to the simulator platform folder. you ignite an spark in my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data you want to display is really in the data base.

Comment: my dataBase is pre populated.

Comment: Still, make sure it's there. Also, make sure you are retrieving it correctly. You are only **assuming** everything is there.